# Angular 6 using ViewChild

Tags: angular

How can I have 2 buttons with the same function that will toggle but both are in different component?

[image: See Here]

and here is how the `m_quick_sidebar_toggle` is being called

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { $ } from 'protractor';

   @Directive({
       selector: '[mQuickSidebarOffcanvas]'
      })
   export class QuickSidebarOffcanvasDirective
    implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
       constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const offcanvas = new mOffcanvas(this.el.nativeElement, {
        overlay: true,
        baseClass: 'm-quick-sidebar',
        closeBy: 'm_quick_sidebar_close',
        toggleBy: 'm_quick_sidebar_toggle'
    });
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {}
```

}

Comment: Hi can you add some code, that will show what all you have tried.

Comment: Maybe use a shared service. And please don't put your questions like this, add some code, show what you have done, this attracts downvotes! We can't help if we don't know your approach.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? It's not really clear from your question. These two functions would be the same. But are they going to be related to each other? Meaning, does calling the function on one component affect the other component? If so, you can create a shared service and do the needful using it. If not, then what exactly is the issue if you just define the same functions in these two components?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `subject` or `BehaviorSubject` from `rxjs`.

Imagine having three components: The main one that recieve the data. The left and the right that send the data. Here's the struct.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonService{
  private data$ = new Subject<any>();
  public dataEvent = this.data$.asObservable();

  public setData(data){
    this.data$.next(data);
  }
}
```

left component

```
export class LeftComponent{
  constructor(
    private service: CommonService
  ) { }

  sendData(){
    this.commonService.setData("my data from left component");
  }
}
```

left component html

```
<span (click)="sendData()"> Send data</span>
```

right component

```
export class RightComponent{
  constructor(
    private service: CommonService
  ) { }

  sendData(){
    this.commonService.setData("my data from right component");
  }
}
```

right component html

```
<span (click)="sendData()"> Send data</span>
```

The main component

```
export class MainComponent{
  public data= "";
  constructor(
    private service: CommonService
  ) { 
      this.service.dataEvent
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
      });
    }
}
```

right component html

```
<p>Data sent from components : {{data}}</p>
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: This is no doubt, a optimised and proper solution. Whatever i posted , was just a simpler version, and i tried to complete that in a single component. Anyways, i have a lot to learn. Thanks mate :)

Comment: You're welcome, since I have this scenario in a lot of cases at work I just over-simplified the logic, but if you can use, instead of Subject, `viewChild` or `EventEmitter` to do the same thing. It's just a different approach, but these logic requries particular things. IE: if you use viewChild both of the left and right component **needs** to be into the flagComponent.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

If your application is small then you can manage through a flag in a global service.

// Service

```
@Injectable()
export class ToggleService {
    private _toggleFlag: boolean = false;

    public get isVisible(){
        return this._toggleFlag;
    }

    public toggle() {
        this._toggleFlag = !this._toggleFlag;
    }
}
```

let "**toggleService**" is the injected instance name of the service "**ToggleService**".

// Toggle button Code

```
<button (click)="toggleService.toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

// Message button code

```
<button *ngIf="toggleService.isVisible">Messages (10)</button>
```

**Approach 2**

If your application is too big and has a lot of similar dependencies then above code will make your code messy. In this case, you can use "**ngRX**" state management. For this, you can refer to the following links.

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/state-management/ngrx/

https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b

Answer (score 0):

Create a global service, that would be common to all components. And when clicking on the button, check the global flag value and toggle between the button functionalities.

```
someFunction(){
    if(this.global.flag){
        this.global.flag = false;
        console.log('do something')
    }
    else{
        this.global.flag = true;
        console.log('toggle the functionality');
    }
```

Comment: If you do that the component that use `this.global.flag` will not "listen" to that change since is not a Subject or a Behavior Subject. Acting this way, you should manually call a function in the FlagComponent from the others, that read `this.global.flag` and execute some logic. But that's is a very bad way.

Answer (score 0):

In the first common ancestor component of these two component use @ViewChild to get a reference to the buttons, then using rxjs merge do:

```
...
@ViewChild('firstButton') firstButton : ElementRef;
@ViewChild('secondButton') secondButton : ElementRef;
...
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    merge(
        fromEvent(firstButton.nativeElement,'click'),
        fromEvent(secondButton.nativeElement,'click')
    ).subscribe( () => toggleFunction() )
}
```

I assumed toggleFunction is part of the ancestor component but even if it's not you can do another @ViewChild to get the component that provides toggle functionality then do:

```
elementThatProvidesToggle.toggle()
```